# Why is this arbitrary-looking identity of arithmetic functions "obvious"?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, alternative-proof, arithmetic-functions

This question is about exercise 2.31 in Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*.

The question asks us the following: if $f$ is a multiplicative arithmetic function, and $g$ is a completely multiplicative arithmetic function, and furthermore for all primes $p$ and $n \geq 1$ we have the relation
$$
f(p^{n+1}) = f(p)f(p^n) - g(p)f(p^{n-1}),
$$
then for all $n, m$
$$
f(n)f(m) = \sum_{d \mid \gcd(n, m)} g(d) f\left(\frac{nm}{d^2}\right).
$$
More than any exercise so far in this book, this looks completely arbitrary to me. I have solved it: you can consider the question only for $n=p^a, m=p^b$, and then it follows for arbitrary $n, m$ by multiplicativity of $f, g$; and we can prove it for $p^a \leq p^b$ by induction on $a$. But that has really taught me nothing: I don't understand why it might make some sense that this is true.

If $g(p) = 0$ for all primes $p$, then the relation we start from becomes $f(p^n) = f(p)^n$ -- i.e., $f$ is completely multiplicative. Thus maybe we can see the $g(p)f(p^{n-1})$ as a sort of *error term* of the complete multiplicativity of $f$. But this doesn't help me see why the result makes sense.

Another approach I tried was noting that the relation allows us to write $f(p^k)$ as a polynomial in $f(p), g(p)$, but I wrote out a few and I didn't see a pattern I understood.

So my question is: where does this identity come from? How should I understand it, visualize it, "get" it? How would one come up with an exercise like this?

Comment: Can you come up with some examples besides completely multiplicative $f$. See if it comes up often enough, how this formula would become a lemma for larger proofs because it was used so often.

Comment: There is an example in the exercise after: $f = \sigma_\alpha$, where $\sigma_\alpha(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d^\alpha$, and $g(n) = n^\alpha$. I can see that that works, but it doesn't help me to understand a general pattern. Also, the exercise before is about proving that the Bell series for such $f$ for prime $p$ is $1/(1 - f(p)x + g(p)x^2)$, which is not so hard to prove, and suggests that such $f, g$ pairs are somewhat common/interesting (and lends further credence to the "complete multiplicativity error term" approach) but I still don't see how it relates to the identity to be proved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This identity a generalisation of the fact that

$$ f(m)f(n) = f(mn) $$

whenever $(m,n)=1$, which holds for any multiplicative function $f$. On seeing this, it's a natural question what happens when $m$ and $n$ are not coprime.

So we're asking for what $f(m)f(n)$ is for a multiplicative function for general $n$. We expect that $f(mn)$ is a 'main term' - indeed, if $f$ is completely multiplicative, then this is exactly what it is. And we know that it is also what it is when $(m,n)=1$. So we expect something like

$$ f(m)f(n) = f(mn) + E$$

where $E$ is some correction term that should depend only on $(m,n)$ and $mn$, and should vanish if $(m,n)=1$ or if $f$ is completely multiplicative.

The exercise gives an explicit form for $E$. As you say, there is some amount of calculation involved, but a small amount of trial and error would naturally lead to the correct form. One might begin, for example, by saying that we should measure how far the multiplicative $f$ is from being completely multiplicative. Completely multiplicative means $f(p^{n+1})=f(p)f(p^n)$, so one might define the function $F(p^{n})=f(p^{n+1})-f(p)f(p^n)$.

If you try and put that into $f(m)f(n)-f(mn)-E$ then it becomes apparent that it would be very convenient for an inductive argument if $F(p^n)$ could be 'factored' as $g(p)f(p^{n-1})$. Thus the hypothesis in the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing more than what you said : it is an equation between operators on multiplicative functions so we look at $n=p^a, m=p^b$ where the equation takes a much simpler form. It comes from modular forms and Euler products of the form $\prod_p \frac1{1-f(p) p^{-s}+g(p) p^{-2s}}=\sum_n f(n) n^{-s}$

The eigenforms (modular forms with multiplicative coefficients) satisfy those relations with $g(p)= p^{k-1}$ or $g(p)= \chi(p)p^{k-1}$ ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecke_operator#Explicit_formula) and [there](http://math.mit.edu/~brubaker/Math784/hecketheory.pdf) p.11). Modular forms are the topics of other books by Apostol which explains why it appears as an exercice in Introduction to Analytic Number Theory.

Comment: Can you expand on "It comes from modular forms"? It seems like that is getting at something deeper.

Comment: The eigenforms satisfy those relations with $g(p)= p^{2k-1}$ or $g(p)= \chi(p)p^{2k-1}$ ([here](http://math.mit.edu/~brubaker/Math784/hecketheory.pdf) p.11) it is in the other books by Apostol which explains why it appears as an exercice in Introduction to Analytic Number Theory